# URLrewrite rule to replace hyphen with %20

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using tuckey.org rewrite urlrewrite filter and I would like to create rule for url with hypen.
like from /author/**person-name** to /topics/Author/**Person Name**

In above rule, hyphen must be replace with space %20 in url and Uppercase of Author and Person Name

Can someone help with writing rule for this?

Comment: What you have done yourself so far? Show us your code.

Comment: I want something like this in 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
    RewriteRule ^teste/?([^/]*)?$ /busca-cidade/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>


# Maps this:
#    /teste/Apto-Padrao
# To:
#    /busca-cidade/Apto%20Padrao


Till now I tried with below but none of the rule matches fine

<rule match-type="wildcard">
 <from>*?-*</from>
 <to type="forward" last="true">/topics/Author/$1%20$2</to>
</rule>
<rule match-type="regex">
 <from>^/author/?([^/]*)?$</from>
 <to type="forward" last="true">/topics/Author/$1</to>
</rule>